# magento install "Too many arguments, expected arguments"

Tags: magento2, php, magento-enterprise, configuration, installation

I get "Too many arguments, expected arguments" when I use the template php magento/bin setup:install \
   --admin-firstname=John \
   --admin-lastname=Smith \
   --admin-email=jsmith@mail.com \
   --admin-user=admin \
   --admin-password=password1 \
   --base-url=http://magento.local/ \
   --db-host=localhost \
   --db-name=magento \
   --db-user=magento \
   --db-password=magento \
   --currency=USD \
   --timezone=America/Chicago \
   --language=en_US \
   --use-rewrites=1

Answer (score 0):

The back slash \ is there to hash out the hidden line return. However if you have typed in the command from the official documentation into your linux command line without the hidden linefeeds this error will appear.

Simply remove the back slashes.